# YouTube video autoplay on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube-api, html5-video

I made a landing page with article blocks and some of them are containing video content from YouTube.

When user scrolls the page, and the block which contains the video is in the device viewport, video element must start playing. I made this using YouTube API, but it doesn't work on mobile devices.

Is there a way to make it work on mobile? Or maybe there is another way to embed and control YouTube video without using iFrame?

Comment: Add your code that says what you have tried yet so that others can help?

Comment: I use the simple code snippet from YouTube API documentation to control the video.

Comment: Stackoverflow doest work like that the members could help on an error or issue you are stuck with since you asked about an alternate for ```<iframe>``` is ```<embed>``` or ```object``` see the examples here:https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp